# How do I get Realtek HD Audio 5.1 working on Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, audio, 5.1, realtek-hd-audio

I have problem with Realtek 5.1 driver for Windows 7 x64. I've installed newest drivers for Realtek HD Audio, but 5.1 still doesn't work, the only thing that works is front stereo. However, when I click on single speaker in sound settings test, every one of them work.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I never got surround sound working perfectly in Windows; the only solution that has ever worked was switching operating systems. I now have Ubuntu and enjoying perfect 5.1 sound now, all my boxes are working.

However I think I managed to get the Realtek high definition audio codecs working in Windows 7 though. But there was a lot of struggling. I had to search a long time till I actually got the Realtek audio interface, this one:

[image]

Just go to this link: http://www.realtek.com.tw/downloads/

Install the audio codecs, after the reboot, go to your configuration screen, choose sound, and the audio manager should be integrated in a new menu there. **I'm not sure about this.**

In the speaker tab, you have to check "Speaker fill" to enable the rear speakers.

[image: Fill speakers]

Answer (score 1):

I believe that **the application** you're using must be sending 5.1 audio for it to work.

You can't just play a 2.1 source and expect it to be replicated on all channels.. 5.1 expects a different track for each channel.

The RealTek UI is *really* crappy though, and *it should* have an option to replicate the audio onto all channels, but [it seems you have to use a plug in for that](https://superuser.com/questions/96796/use-all-5-1-speakers-with-a-2-1-audio-source).